# filter sublist in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to use a predicate to find the sublist meet the requirement that contains at least one atomic(not variable).

```
contain_atomic([[a,c,e],[a,e,D],[D,A,E]],X).
X = [[a,c,e],[a,e,D]].
```

So far, I can only turn those sublist whose elements are all variables to empty.

```
all_variable([],[]).
all_variable([A|B],[]):-
    \+atomic(A),
    all_variable(B,[]).
```

And what's next? Am I close to success?

Comment: *"[...] to find the sublist meet these two [...]"* -- I don't understand this formulation. Do you mean "find the sublist *that* meet" or "find *if* the sublist meet"?

Comment: find the sublist that meet those two requirement. Or maybe one that find the sublist contains at least one atomic(not variable). It's the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you write a predicate that states what must hold for a *single* sublist to be included in the result (I leave this task as an easy exercise for your concrete case):

```
your_property(Sublist) :-
    ...
```

Then, use `include/3` to filter all sublists that satisfy this property:

`include(your_property, Lists0, Lists)`

Always (at least) *consider* using `include/3` and `exclude/3` when filtering lists, because they simplify the task by only necessitating a description of the property for a single element.

Comment: `include/3` and `exclude/3` are incorrect in many cases. Take `p(1). p(2).` and `include(p,[X],Xs).`

Comment: That's indeed an unfortunate case. They are safe though when their arguments are sufficiently instantiated, which is also very often. Op's problem is unfortunately inherently not monotonic in any case, independent of these library predicates.

Comment: The OP's problem is not only non-monotonic, it is also non-logical. But now another non-logical layer is introduced - unless there are always clean instantiation errors around.

Comment: A good implementation of `your_property/1` will raise such instantiation errors in cases that would otherwise lead to unsound behaviour in this combination. I therefore do not see your point specifically against `include/3` and `exclude/3`: You may just as well say that `p/1` is not safely usable in this case. It would be safe to use it with `include/3` and `exclude/3` if you raise an instantiation error when its argument is a variable.

Comment: The point is: `p/1` alone is safe and monotonic, it is only unsafe due to the problematic use in `include/3`.

Comment: I see the point, and it is unfortunate. However, you can also write `p/1` in such a way that it is safe and monotonic, *and* its use in `include/3` is always correct. For predicates you intend to use only in connection with `include/3` and `exclude/3`, like `your_property/1` above, I would do this.